# Setting PHP Query into a nested array

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to use PHP to logically store all of that data in a nested associative arrays, and then whenever I loop through the data or need to reference the data I would refer to the array pointer rather than doing new queries each time.

For example:

My query is

```
$query = $db->query("
SELECT
    c.id campaign_id,
    c.campaign_title,
    c.start_date campaign_start_date,
    c.end_date campaign_end_date,
    cat.id category_id,
    cat.category_title,
    n.id nominee_id,
    n.title nominee_title,
    u.id voter_id,
    u.fullname voter_name
FROM
    campaign c
LEFT JOIN categories cat ON cat.campaign_id = c.id
LEFT JOIN category_nominees cn ON cn.category_id = cat.id
LEFT JOIN nominees n ON n.id = cn.nominee_id
LEFT JOIN category_votes cv ON cv.campaign_id = c.id
AND cv.category_id = cat.id
AND cv.nominee_id = n.id
LEFT JOIN users u on u.id = cv.user_id
WHERE
    c.active = 1
ORDER BY
    u.fullname,
    c.campaign_title,
    cat.category_order,
    cat.category_title,
    cn.nominee_order,
    n.title
") or die(mysqli_error());
```

and im trying to set up the nested array like

```
$array = array() ;

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {

  $array[$row['campaign_id']] = $row['campaign_id'];
  $array[$row['campaign_id']]['campaign_title'] = $row['campaign_title'];
  $array[$row['campaign_id']]['campaign_start_date'] = $row['campaign_start_date'];
  $array[$row['campaign_id']]['campaign_end_date'] = $row['campaign_end_date'];
  $array[$row['campaign_id']]['campaign_title'] = $row['campaign_title'];
  $array[$row['campaign_id']]['category_id'] = $row['category_id'];
  $array[$row['campaign_id']]['category_id']['category_title'] = $row['category_title'];
}
```

So whenever I point to:

```
$array[2][3]['category_title']
```

It would print the category title

Do you have any ideas? I literally been at it for months and can't figure it out.

Comment: Sry but i do not understand at all what you're doing. Could you show us a short example of the resulting array you want ?

Comment: Are you sure the SQL request is involved in the problem, or is this just how to access values in the arrays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    if (!isset($row['campaign_id'])) {
        $array[$row['campaign_id']] = $row;
    }
    if (!isset($array[$row['campaign_id']]['categories'])) {
        $array[$row['campaign_id']]['categories'] = array();
    } 
    $array[$row['campaign_id']]['categories'][$row['category_id']] = array('category_id' => $row['category_id'], 'category_title' => $row['category_title']);
    }
}
```

`$row` is already an associative array, you don't need to assign each element separately. You only need to deal specially with the category information, which has to be put into a nested associative array that I've called `categories`. So you would access it as

```
$array[0]['categories'][1]['category_title']
```

You can loop over all the categories with:

```
foreach ($array[$campaign]['categories'] as $cat) {
    echo "Category ID: {$cat['category_id']} Title: {$cat['category_title']}<br>";
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Would it be ok if instead of isset we do !array_key_exists? Wouldn't that be a better choice?

Comment: You can use that if you like. I prefer `isset()`, since it's terser and easier to read IMHO.

Comment: How would you do a foreach loop to show each category title?

Comment: Added it to the answer.